# How does Delphine know where the Horn is?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I finished the quest `The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller`. The Greybeards sent me to Ustengrav. Upon completion I saw the note from Delphine. In a bid to learn my last word of "Dah" I went to Riverwood since she was the one who left the note for me.

When I meet her, she tells me "You are the one the Grey-Beards summoned and why I did so and so". Which is why she beat me to the horn of the Wind Caller.

But How?

Maybe she heard the summons in the story line, when the Greybeards summoned the Dovahkiin and deduced, BUT HOW?

HOW did she know to go to Ustengrav, which is exactly like a lot of Nordic ruins?

And why Ustengrav?

Comment: Also, how did she manage to obtain the horn while still leaving the dungeon full of monsters? (and armed traps, if there were any)

Comment: She probably has resources to various intelligence from other blades, or she wouldn't have known that the dragon stone is in bleak barrel falls in the first place.

Comment: @Joren 100 Sneak and 100 Illusion with all the perks, obviously.

Comment: More to the point: Leaving a note instructing anyone who would be looking for the horn (including those she didn't want getting it) on exactly where to find you and what to say isn't the most watertight plan.

Comment: Closing this. Questions about plot holes cannot be reasonably answered beyond speculation. More on meta [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/game-canon-questions-which-extend-beyond-the-context-of-the-story-and-its-materi).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All questions answered.

**How did she know?**
She's the acting Grandmaster of the Blades. If a [half-naked drug addict](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Caius_Cosades) can be Grand Spymaster during better times, she can probably figure a few things out.

It's also possible that everyone in Tamriel knew and the Greybeards were the last to know because the only person who ever goes near there is Klimmek. I mean, even bandits and necromancers were trying to raid the place.

**Why Ustengrav?**
Well, it is where Jurgen Windcaller's tomb is. Seems like a logical location.

**How did she get in and out without killing anyone?**
Well, of course she killed everyone. But then ten days elapsed and they were all okay. And the traps reset. It wasn't hard because she's essential.

Comment: Your last answer breaks the fourth wall!!

Comment: Ahh, if only there were a console for real life.
> player.additem F 999999999
> tim

Comment: @Alex it only works if your starting F value is above 1 million

Comment: @yx. :( Guess it's back to work tomorrow after all...

Comment: Evidently her power level is over 9000